# Is there a way of getting a Read Receipt information of a message from Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

i'm working on an application for teams and I need to know when a recipient read a message that was sent from a teams bot.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no feature available** to get Read Receipt information of a message from a Microsoft Teams BOT

Answer (score 0):

This item remains on the backlog in Teams UserVoice,
Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com).